# Minimum of this expression

Tags: calculus

I was given a problem to minimise

$$[(x-y)^2+(12+\sqrt{1-x^2} -\sqrt{4y})^2]$$

Where x,y are real, I have managed to solve it, but it took a lot of time and effort, can anyone provide a short way?

Comment: Well, you have to at least provide the method you used, otherwise, how can we compare which is "shorter"?

Comment: Show how you managed solving it . Is the quantity in second radical sign correct?

Comment: Coordinate geometry.

Comment: Come on, @T.S.L. -- it is pretty clearly implied that he took $x$ and $y$ derivatives and set both to zero and solved, and he is looking for a cooler method than that. Or maybe not, and the cooler method he is looking for *is* to take those derivatives...

Comment: The question is correct

Comment: @mark I'm looking for a way in which a person doing this question for the first time could do it in 3-4 mins.

Comment: Let us suppose you have found a solution $(x_0,y_0)$. Could you please rewrite for us the problem with a change of variables like, for instance,  $x=x_0+x'$ and  $y=y_0+y'$ to  see if it somehow simplifies a bit?

Comment: @Laurent I didn't do it that way..

Comment: How did you do it then?

Comment: As I said, I did it using coordinate geometry, there's just one thing to be visualised by that method, I was wanting a calculus approach..

Comment: Without much thinking, x=y=0 looks good. Is that what you got?

Comment: @NoChance so according to you, the answer is 169?

Comment: The answer is 4$\sqrt5$-1.

Comment: That is better indeed!

Comment: Shall I post my approach?

Comment: That would be a good idea. At least some one may spot an error in case there is any.

Comment: The expression that is written is basically the square of the distance from any point x on the circle $x^2+(y-12)^2=1$ and the parabola $y^2=4x$ if you look at things carefully, so I had to find the shortest distance between these curves.

Comment: I don't see how to get anywhere near your minimum; the best I find is well over 70... But it is clearly wrong for womebody to downvote this, so I am upvoting it.

Comment: Wait, since this is the square of that distance, the answer should be 81-8$\sqrt5$ and not what I posted earlier.

Comment: A plot can be obtained by google here:https://www.google.ca/search?q=(x-y)%5E2%2B)12%2Bsqer(1-x%5E2)#q=(x-y)%5E2%2B(12%2Bsqrt(1-x%5E2)-sqrt(4y))%5E2

Answer (score 1):

So, the goal here is to minimize: $f(x,y)=(x−y)^2+(12+\sqrt{1−x^2}-\sqrt{4y})^2$.

Notice that $x \in [-1,1]$ and $y \in [0,\infty)$ because of the constraint from both square roots.

We are looking to minimize any positive expressions, $(x−y)^2$ and $\sqrt{1−x^2}$, and maximize and negative expressions, $-\sqrt{4y}$.

Intuitively,

$(x-y)^2$ vs $(12+\sqrt{1−x^2}-\sqrt{4y})^2$

While we want to minimize both expressions, the latter expression "grows" more quickly e.g. $[(12+1)^2-12^2] - [(2+1)^2-2^2]>0$

Thus, it is straightforward to check (you can do this by taking the derivative or intuitively) that the minimum occurs at $x=1$. Therefore, we can turn this into an optimization problem of a single variable by substituting the value $x=1$ into the function: $(1-y)^2+(12-\sqrt{4y})^2$

$\dfrac{d}{dy}\left[(1-y)^2+(12-\sqrt{4y})^2\right]=2y-\dfrac{24}{\sqrt{y}}+2=0        \quad\quad$ at $y=\frac{1}{3} [-2+(1945-36 \sqrt{2919})^{1/3}+(1945+36 \sqrt{2919})^{1/3}]\approx 4.5969$

$f(1,4.5969)\approx72.4115$ which is smaller than the previously mentioned $f(0,0)=169$

Comment: I totally agree with your answer. Using the formal expression of $y$ you gave, the minimum value corresponds to the real root of $z^3-433 z^2+65088 z-2822400=0$ which is $$z=\frac{1}{3} \left(433-\frac{7775}{\sqrt[3]{140112
   \sqrt{2919}-7538831}}+\sqrt[3]{140112 \sqrt{2919}-7538831}\right)\approx 72.411453805$$

Comment: Yes, but I get 63.11 using my approach.

Comment: I think there might be a problem, either calculationally or conceptually, with your approach. I used Mathematica to confirm that the global minimum occurs at the coordinates shown above. Of course taking the derivative and solving the problem long way will give you the same answer, the question asked for a shorter method, which I believe is to solve for the x-coordinate intuitively.
Note that the problem that I solved is the question originally posted and the problem that you solved might be a different problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Even though it's the same problem I don't see where or why my answer/method is wrong.. Anyways, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If it's unclear , ask for any clarifications.
[image]

Comment: What's wrong in this?